# Protractor: How to select first available date in ui-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, protractor, e2e-testing, gulp-protractor

I am writing e2e tests using protractor , I have one `ui-datepicker` which has some dates are disabled or some are enabled.
How can I select the first available date in month
Note: The ui-datepicker is not in my angular app, it is external link which in not angular app.
Please advice accordingly, Thank you 
Code of available date

```
<td class="  start_day ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="7" data-year="2017" role="gridcell" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false" id="ui-datepicker-0-7-3"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-state-focus" href="#" tabindex="-1">3</a></td>
```

Comment: try sendKyes("Date"). it will work i guess

Comment: @SureshSalloju In my case it is autocomplete menu. I can't fill date maually